# Can you put two separate p tags on the same line and still edit them separately

Tags: html, css, text, position

So I have a horizontal bar on my page and I want to put several `<p>` tags on that bar so that when I, later down the road, want to start to make a responsive layout, can have them removed when reaching a specific screen size. But what I want to know is how can I put these `p` sections on the same line without pushing one down underneath the containing section? I've used `display:inline` and `float: left` but I dont like that because you can't format the text to be `text-align: right` or have it be a specific distance from the left side of the screen. For example, if you put `margin-left: 6%` it wont be 6% away from the left side of the screen, it will be 6% away from the element before it and I don't want that. I'm assuming the overall outcome will be absolute positioning but I want to see if there were any other options first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give `display:inline-block;` to your `p` class and a proper `width` and they will come in one line, having `display:inline` remove the option of giving dimension to the element!
do it this way :

<kbd>[**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/qa5x8/2/)</kbd>

```
p {
    height:100%;
    width:50%;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: this did help in the issue regarding the margin formatting/text-align, but I still have the issue of the second text being a level underneath the first one. What I did was have all `p` in the `div` container have `display:inline-block` , `height:100%` , and `width:100%` and each `p` has a defined `width` with `margin` and `padding` to zero (since I'm just trying to get everything set up first) [Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nwb9sjm5m9xnupv/Screenshot%202014-02-02%2014.48.08.png)

Comment: here's just the part with the bar with the text. If it's possible I'd also want the `a` to be apart of the line too but I can always switch it back to `position:absolute` if I have to.

Answer (score 1):

display:inline-block is the key

the main difference in between inline and inline-block is that, inline-block allows you to specify the dimensions, paddings, and margins of the element whereas inline block simply wraps the element.

Answer (score 0):

Try `display:inline` and give `paddings` as you like just as like this:

```
p{
    display:inline;
    padding:5px;
}
```

here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gyHXx/